# Error w sockets in Powershell: SocketException

Tags: powershell, sockets

My code below outputs a error message on the line `$server.Start()`, and I can't figure out what is wrong. The value in `$addr` is the IP `192.168.43.68`.

The error occours on the server code. I am using sockets as a pipeline to communicate b/w two Powershell scripts running on the same PC.

Error message:

```
+ $server.Start()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SocketException
```

code: (TCP socket - server)

```
$header = "GO THERE"

# TCP socket - server
#$addr = [ipaddress]'192.168.43.1'
$addr = [Net.DNS]::GetHostEntry([Net.DNS]::GetHostName()).AddressList[0]
Write-Host ("addr: " + $addr)
$port = 1234

$endpoint = New-Object Net.IPEndPoint ($addr, $port)
$server = New-Object Net.Sockets.TcpListener $endpoint
$server.Start()
$cn = $server.AcceptTcpClient()

$stream = $cn.GetStream()
$writer = New-Object IO.StreamWriter($stream)
Write-Host("To TCP socket - server: "+$header)
$writer.WriteLine($header)
$writer.Dispose()

$server.Stop()
```

code: (TCP socket - client)

```
# TCP socket - client
$server = '127.0.0.1'
$port   = 1234

$client = New-Object Net.Sockets.TcpClient
$client.Connect($server, $port)
$stream = $client.GetStream()

$reader = New-Object IO.StreamReader($stream)
$reader.ReadLine()
$reader.Dispose()

$client.Dispose()

Write-Host("From TCP socket - client: "+$reader)
```

Comment: Your code works for me